# 301 redirect TO a dynamic address (not FROM as every other user asks)

Tags: redirect, http-status-code-301

Need an .htaccess rewrite rule to 301 redirect a series of incoming links (from a moved static site) to dynamic links. The key is, I need to point to dynamic (?p=#) so if I move the page again, it won't lose the permalinks that we then direct it to.

Incoming URL:

http://example.com/static.htm

Need 301 redirect to:

http://example.com/?p=34

(Which will then be redirected according to other rules... that I can't predict)

Comment: We need more information.  For starters, what server are you running?

Comment: What type of web server are you using, for example: IIS or Apache? Do you have admin access to the web server?

Comment: Apache... very standard web hosting - php and .htaccess